# Showing Overridden toString() in java repl via console

Tags: java, read-eval-print-loop

I'm trying to check as I go via java repl. I've loaded the file in the repl and I'm trying to view what my overridden toString method is outputting with:

```
java> toString()
java.lang.String res3 = "Evaluation$dqj46can5zk9l1we8xs3@1be11da3"
```

The actual method is:

```
public String toString(){
  return String.format("\nPart ID: " + partID +
  "\nDescription: " + partDescription +
  "\nSell Price: " + partSellPrice);
}
```

Comment: Java doesn't usually have a REPL; and it appears you're printing some kind of inner class instance (the `$` is a bit of a tell).

Comment: Side note: please avoid "new here"/"new to YYY" text in the post unless it is directly related to problem. Also SO is wrong place to ask for tutorial - use search engines to find content (I've removed tutorial request from your post, otherwise it could be immediately closed as "search for tutorials").

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thanks! Will keep that in mind.